# Feedback when deleting own answer is misleading

Tags: bug, status-completed

I typed a response to a [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/best-long-zoom-digital-camera/6736) into the answer field by mistake instead of a comment. I then clicked "delete" on the answer and it told me something like "thanks for voting to delete". But then when I refreshed the page, it was apparently (????) actually deleted.

Deleting your own answer should happen right away and the feedback should be clear (e.g. "your question has been deleted").

**Edit**

OK, it looks like what I saw earlier doesn't happen any more, but there's still a very similar bug present. Here is a specific reproduction recipe. I tested it just now on this very question in meta. This is with Chrome on Mac OS X.

*Steps to reproduce*

1. Go to a question.
2. Click yes to "are you sure you want to answer your own question" dialog (if needed).
3. Type "test 2 - I am going to delete this" into answer field.
4. Click "Post Your Answer".
5. Answer appears under question.
6. Click "delete" link for answer.

*Actual behavior*

1. Dialog reading "Vote to delete this post?" appears.
2. Click OK.
3. Post changes to deleted color and styling, etc.

*Expected behavior*

1. Dialog reading "Really delete your answer?" (or something) appears.
2. Click OK.
3. Post changes to deleted color and styling, etc.

**P.S.**

It is kind of lame that I can't remove the tag status-completed.

Comment: This happens across the stackexchange sites, by the way. There's probably another report on this somewhere.

Comment: Just happened to me this morning. Only in my case, I noticed that while typing the answer, so I cut-pasted the text to a new comment field. To my surprise, once the page was refreshed (I got out and in again), I see the original text still hanging in the answer input box... I had to approve the answer and then delete it.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that it is deleted from everyone but your view, in case you want to undelete it shortly thereafter. I think that's the right way to do it, in case deleting was a mistake or your account was hacked or something like that. I clicked on your question, and I don't see your answer at all.

Comment: That's fine, but the feedback text needs to match what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

There were some css styles associated with direct answer links that prevented the deletion styles from showing up.  These have been simplified, so immediate answer deletions can better be seen.

As for the message you saw, I'm not able to reproduce - if you see it again, please let me know with the actions you took before deleting.

Comment: It's still awkwardly worded. I will edit the answer.